# In-app announcement of new/related apps?

Tags: ios, open-source, alert, in-app

Is there an open source library for announcing new apps via an in-app alert within another app?

iVersion is close to what I am talking about, but not quite, from what I see of it.

Example:
* App-A is purchased by person; in this app I would like to embed a function to alert the person when a new related app is published
* Sometime later, App-B is published - would like the users of App-A to be notified, because the apps are related

And of course, if someone wants to cancel or ignore these alerts, they should disappear and not return on future launches of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a classic case for push notifications. Can't see any advantage to necessarily linking these alerts to application launches or updates - you can just manually send a push notification to all users of app A when app B comes out (unless you launch new applications by the hour).

Comment: I think you are right. As a follow up question, are there any pre-existing libraries to handle this or is the typical solution to 'roll your own'?

Comment: As one who has rolled his own, I'm not quite sure. Could be though

Answer (score 0):

As you said, iVersion isn't intended for this, but my other library iNotify is:

https://github.com/nicklockwood/iNotify

iNotify polls a remote plist file for messages and then displays them on app launch. It has more-or-less the same interface as iVersion and has buttons to dismiss, remind, etc.